# Are IOs a separate power consumer from the rest of the µcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, power, gpio

The [ATmega2560 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf) specifies the DC draw through the VCC/GND is 200 mA (AMR).
The DC current of a single I/O pin can go up to 40 mA (AMR).

It doesn't make sense that I can draw 40 mA from every I/O pin because (without taking all other internal µcontroller modules into consideration) I would reach the maximum draw by maxing 200/40 = 5 I/O pins.

Does this mean that I am limited to a specific equivalent of current source/sink from all operating I/Os at a given time?
Will it be always lower than 200 mA total and 40 mA on each I/O pin?

Comment: The rules are simple: up to 40mA per pin with a 200mA max total.  The power bond wires and power paths on the ic have a limited current carrying capacity of 200mA.

Comment: You have to stay within both limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a simplified block diagram of an MCU with one I/O *(push/pull output for the sake of simplicity)*:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwBj6J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

<sup>I put BJTs for a push-pull output but can be MOSFETs. MOSFETs totem pole outputs are inverting, so not to make it confusing I used BJTs totem pole.</sup>

As you can see, the VDD line caries all the current for both I/O and the core. So the max allowed current consumption is given for everything included (I/Os, internal modules such as timers, etc.) and is limited by the internal wiring mainly.

The I/O limit basically comes from the transistor design.

So you should not exceed the I/O current as well as total current limits.

Comment: More likely to be MOSFETs than JFETs; I've never seen an output stage implemented in JFETs. Using depletion-mode devices for push-pull outputs is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @Hearth you're right. Thanks for pointing out. Editing...

Answer (score 4):

DC Current per I/O Pin ................................................ 40.0mA <-- means what it means

DC Current VCC and GND Pins................................. 200.0mA <- this is on the VCC / GND pins

There are 4 VCC pin so up to 800mA, but you need to keep in mind this would be total possible current consumption which includes the I/Os but also the the rest of the MCU.

It also depends if you are using the IO as open drain for example, where you'd have 5 GND pins so a bit more of allowable current.

Comment: Are you sure that the 200 mA limit is per pin? The fact that it says "per I/O pin," but it says "Vcc and GND pins" instead of "per Vcc or GND pin," makes it sound to me like there's a 200 mA limit for all Vcc pins combined, as well as a 200 mA limit for all GND pins combined.

Comment: Yeah there is no way that you can get 800 mA through this MCU without damaging it.

Comment: @Tanner-reinstateLGBTpeople yes because it is general datasheet, otherwise it would have different specs for different package with different amount of pin. It has mostly to do with how many gold bond wire is there from the pin to the silicon and the silicon design itself. Another aspect is that if it was for all, it would be only 50mA per pin in this case, about the same as an IO which wouldn't make much sense design wise.

Answer (score 1):

DC Current per I/O Pin ................................................ 40.0mA

DC Current VCC and GND Pins................................. 200.0mA

That is not very specific, vague even.

From the [datasheet p356](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf#page=356), Notes 3 & 4.

> 3. Although each I/O port can sink more than the test conditions (20mA at VCC = 5V, 10mA at VCC = 3V) under steady state
>    conditions (non-transient), the following must be observed:

> ATmega640/1280/2560:
> 1.)The **sum of all IOL, for ports J0-J7, A0-A7, G2 should not exceed 200mA**.
> 2.)The sum of all IOL, for ports C0-C7, G0-G1, D0-D7, L0-L7 should not exceed 200mA.
> 3.)The sum of all IOL, for ports G3-G4, B0-B7, H0-B7 should not exceed 200mA.
> 4.)The sum of all IOL, for ports E0-E7, G5 should not exceed 100mA.
> 5.)The sum of all IOL, for ports F0-F7, K0-K7 should not exceed 100mA.
> If IOL exceeds the test condition, VOL may exceed the related specification. Pins are not guaranteed to sink current greater
> than the listed test condition.

> 4. Although each I/O port can source more than the test conditions (20mA at VCC = 5V, 10mA at VCC = 3V) under steady
>    state conditions (non-transient), the following must be observed:

> ATmega640/1280/2560:
> 1)The **sum of all IOH, for ports J0-J7, G2, A0-A7 should not exceed 200mA**.
> 2)The sum of all IOH, for ports C0-C7, G0-G1, D0-D7, L0-L7 should not exceed 200mA.
> 3)The sum of all IOH, for ports G3-G4, B0-B7, H0-H7 should not exceed 200mA.
> 4)The sum of all IOH, for ports E0-E7, G5 should not exceed 100mA.
> 5)The sum of all IOH, for ports F0-F7, K0-K7 should not exceed 100mA.

Each pin can be used as a source (generating current) and/or a sink (sinking current to ground) via MOSFETs.

[image]

[Sink Source Simulation](https://wulflemm.com/war/circuitjs.html?startCircuit=../applied/sink-source.txt) showing driving a 20mA LED sourcing or sinking.

Total current for J0-J7, A0-A7, G2 must be less than 200mA sourcing AND  sinking.  G2 could be 40mA maximum sourcing AND / OR sinking (ignoring Note 3 & 4 constraints of 20mA at VCC = 5V and 10mA at VCC = 3V), which means the other 16 pins must be less than 160 mA sourcing AND sinking.  So 10mA / pin or use an external driver.  (Since G2 can sink or source, the extra 40mA as source or sink is available, but that is dangerous.)

As a designer, you are constrained by the chip, but free to use the pins as required.  Everything is a trade off.  All to simplify the overall design.  Max G2 but limit J0-J7 and A0-A7.

Specifically the ATmega2560 can sink and source 800mA of current, within the limitations of Notes 3 & 4.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not specifications how much the current is or can be, nor nominal operating conditions.

Those are absolute maximum ratings, and if you exceed them, the device may be permanently damaged.

In fact the MCU operation is not guaranteed after nominal operating conditions, just that there should be no permanent damage if you exceed nominal operating conditions but stay within absolute maximum ratings.

The limits come from how much the structures inside the MCU can handle, such as on chip wiring, pin bond wiring, etc.

There are even further limits, such as current limit per port.

In theory you can put enough load on pins of different ports that their sum reaches 100mA per port and 200mA per chip. However, doing so is not a good idea.